# Using functions as parameter or use them directly in clojure?

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

i have this two functions and i use share-card-to-player in share-cards. Should i not rather pass share-card-to-player as argument or use it as anonymous function?

In the way, i am using it, i doubt, that i am using it in a functional way, because i am basically referencing to a global variable namely the function `share-card-to-player`. Is that assumption correct?

```
(defn share-card-to-player [game [player cards]]
  (assoc-in game [:players player :cards ]
            cards))

(defn share-cards [{players :players cards :cards :as game}]
  (reduce share-card-to-player game
          (map vector
               (keys players)
               (->>  cards
                     (partition (/ (count cards)
                                   (count players)))))))
```

Comment: Matter of opinion, but I'd say it's OK as-is. share-cards-to-player is rather short but naming it improves the program's readability. A third alternative is for share-card-to-player to be a named function with limited scope, by binding to share-cards a function in a closure where share-card-to-player was defined: (def share-cards (let [share-card-to-player (fn ...)] (fn ...))) However, the way you have presented it is the easiest to work with in a debugger, where you can instrument share-card-to-player with a breakpoint.

Answer (score 5):

> i am basically referencing to a global variable namely the function `share-card-to-player`

`assoc-in` is a global variable. `/` is a global variable. `count` is a global variable. Should you avoid them all? It will be tough to get anything done! The problem with globals is *mutation*, and functions are not mutable.

You can define `share-card-to-player` as an anonymous local function if you want. But it's fine as is. Extracting it as a function parameter would make sense only if you expect you would want to pass another function to it at another use site.

Answer (score 4):

Passing in the function as a parameter would only make sense to me if you plan to pass in different functions in other parts of your program to change the behavior of `share-cards`.

In your particular example, I'd even consider factoring out the call to `map` if you can give a good name to that thing because it takes longer to read and understand that code.

To summarize:

- Functions as parameter should change the behavior.
- Factoring out things to their own functions, even if only used in one place of your program, makes sense if you can give a good name to what the code does.